# FCM push notification without payload to Android device

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor, android-push-notification, capacitor-plugin

I have an angular application deployed as PWA, iOS and Android app (Capacitor). This app rely on Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notification:

In android, I test this with the FCM console, and, as you can see from this `console.log`

[image: here is a dump of the notification]

in the *pushNotificationReceived* event handler, I've title, body and data fields from the notification.

But when the notification is tapped (e.g. when the app is closed), **I lose its informations**, as you can see from this console.log in *pushNotificationActionPerformed* event handler:

[image]

Inside the "data" field I have no more info about the original push notification.

**This happens only with android, iOS has 'gcm.notification.data' object and PWA 'body' object.** where I can find all the info I need.

What am I missing in order to get those info also in android?

Answer (score 0):

Relating on capacitor developer, this depends on Android OS:

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4934